# Why Firefox go to previous page in our website?

Tags: firefox, redirect, referer

here is our website: seeyar.fr

I don't understand the behaviour of Firefox v44.0. When we go to any posts, firefox redirect to referer. Exemple when we come from google search: post load then redirect to google after few second...

Nota:
-home page works, it concerns only posts.
-Works with firefox in private navigation mode, chrome and edge

Regards

Comment: Are you using any javascript redirection for any other purposes on your site?

Answer (score 0):

this works when adblock is on. So adsense on our site is the reason of redirection. But how to fix this? is it a bug?